# Accessible hidden file input

Tags: html, input, accessibility, wai-aria

I am trying to figure out the way to replace `<input type='file' />` and make it's replacement accessible as the mentioned input itself.

**Question is:** Can I have it both ways, or is `type='file'` the key of the accesibility keys?

My approach:

I've basically told the browser to forget about `type='file'`'s existence with CSS:

```
input[type=file] {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

Prepared it's replacement:

```
<input type='file' />
<label for="file">Upload your file</label>
<input type='text' id='file' />
```

Fixed OS' styles with some pretty CSS and added the JS (jQuery) code to handle the file browser displaying:

```
$("#file").on("focus", function(ev) {
    $(this).siblings("[type='file']").first().focus();
});
```

And handled upload for the file input so it displays filenames and does other cool stuff browsers prevent.

Do I need to add some extra aria attributes to make it more descriptive? Should I, for example, prevent `type='file'` from being selected with tab by setting `tabindex="-1"`, so the person-in-need-of-accessibility does not get confused while opening file browser two times in a row within short time period? Should I add an `id='file-label'` on my `<label>` element and `aria-describbedby='file-label'` on the `type='file'`? Or should I just give it all up and use the filthy standard `type='file'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There's no corresponding role in ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#input-file) for the `input[file]` tag. You are using five different ways to hide the `input[file]` element (`display:none`, `visibility: hidden`, `opacity:0`, `width=0;height=0` and offscreen positionning), that's way too much and putting a `tabindex=-1` on a `display:none` element has no effect...

In my humble opinion, it would be better to replace the `input[file]` with a `button` as this button would trigger a click on the hidden `input[file]`.

The `input[text]` would give a curious announcement on the screen reader.

Of course, it could be a good thing to modify the `button` text to specify the selected file after a selection has been done.